# Changing timezone from EWS datetime_received from standard to +2

Tags: python, exchangewebservices, exchangelib

I'm trying to change the timezone from UTC+0  to GMT+2. I have tried a lot but i just can't figure it out any help would be amazing

```
credentials = Credentials(email, wachtwoord)
acc = Account(email, credentials=credentials, autodiscover=True)

for item in acc.inbox.all().order_by('-datetime_received')[:100]:

    print(item.datetime_received)
    #print: 2021-13-09 11:08:31+00:00 
    #print expected: 2021-13-09 13:08:31+02+00
```

Final solution:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

credentials = Credentials(email, password)
acc = Account(email, credentials=credentials, autodiscover=True)
tz = pytz.timezone('Europe/Amsterdam')

for item in acc.inbox.all().order_by('-datetime_received')[:100]:
    dt = item.datetime_received.astimezone(tz)
    print(dt)
```

Comment: Are you trying to change the timezone of `datetime_received` ?

Comment: Can you post sample outputs of the data and the data type?

Comment: Yes sorry for the confusion but that is what im trying.

Comment: Please rephrase your question and consider adding more details, the question is impossible to answer as it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [pytz](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/) to display datetime objects in different timezones.

example:

```
import pytz
from datetime import datetime

ts = datetime.now()
tz = pytz.timezone('Etc/GMT+2')
print(ts.astimezone(tz))
```